# Many to Many join with the least duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Lets say I have two tables. Each table has an ID column.Multiple rows in each table may have the same ID. I need to join the tables on ID selecting each record in each table only once. There is a many to many relationship between the tables. Using Oracle database.

Lets say we have two tables.

Table 1:

```
ID | Office Address
-------------------
1  | A Street
1  | B Street
2  | C street
3  | D Street
```

Table 2:

```
ID | Company Name
------------------
1  | Toys Limited
1  | Toys Incorporated
1  | Toys Unlimited
2  | Best Cakes
4  | Best Boxes
```

and what I want to get is:

```
ID | Company Address              | Company Name
----------------------------------------------
1  | A Street                     | Toys Limited
1  | B Street                     | Toys Incorporated
1  | Null (some value acceptable) | Toys Unlimited
2  | C Street                     | Best Cakes
3  | D Street                     | Null
4  | Null                         | Best Boxes
```

I need to span this query over 10 different tables, with a total of 300 columns, so not having to specify each column would be nice.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: "*Lets say we have two tables*" vs. "*over 10 different tables*" which is it? 10 tables or 2 tables?

Comment: for simplicity two tables. using Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS ID, t1.Office_Address, t2.Company_Name
FROM (
  SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM Table1 t1
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM Table2 t2
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY ID
```

Test it on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d2c96/2)

Comment: I think I get the logic, and this seems like a great solution, but I keep getting "Ivalid Identifier" on ID field.

Comment: Strange, it works on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d2c96/2 May be some table don`t have ID column?

Comment: I've managed to get it to work without the coalesce() function. everything else is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ahhhhh, but without the Coalesce it's difficult to order the results